# Is it possible to make a uninstall script?

Tags: apt, bash, scripts, uninstall

Basically I want a script that executes the following command:
apt remove --purge -y ~PROGRAM~ && apt autoremove -y

Except I could use options to change ~PROGRAM~ to the name of the package I'd like to uninstall.

In the terminal it would look something along the lines of this:
sudo uninstall ~Package name here~

If someone would give me the code required for this or a tutorial on how to do it that would be great!

Comment: You favorite Search Engine will happily provide you with a dozen good bash scripting tutorials. Those are how many of us learned. Advice: For your first script, consider something a bit less destructive if you make a typo or mistake. The script you envision will happily destroy your system utterly if you input certain package names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sudo uninstall"
read uninstallpkg
sudo apt remove --purge -y $uninstallpkg && apt autoremove -y
```

The terminal will prompt you for the package you want to uninstall (as specified with `read uninstallpkg`), type your package in and press enter, and it will uninstall.

As `user535733` noted, this could be dangerous and it is possible to destroy your system, so be sure to use it with caution.

Instead, you can replace `sudo apt remove --purge -y $uninstallpkg && apt autoremove -y` with `sudo apt remove -y $uninstallpkg`, which will be less dangerous than the previous command and will not destroy your system.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way I could make the command accessible from any directory?

Comment: Nevermind: I found a tutorial here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239986/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-any-directory